# Set new TextView to fragment in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I want to add a new `TextView` inside my Fragment. This is my code in the asynctask backgroundjob class:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String json) {

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
        JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
        String code = JO.getString("code");
        String message = JO.getString("message");

        if (code.equals("true")) {
            /**********************************/

            LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
            View mContainer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null);
            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)mContainer.findViewById(R.id.mylinearLayout);

            TextView text = new TextView(linearLayout.getContext());
            text.setText("TEST");
            text.setTextSize(30);

            Log.d("View", "Start");
            try {
                linearLayout.addView(text);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

And this is my fragment class:

```
public class Home extends Fragment {

    public Home() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        TopicBackgroundTask backgroundTask = new TopicBackgroundTask(getActivity());
        backgroundTask.execute("yes");

        // Inflate the layout for this

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }
}
```

**NOTE** : `Home` fragment and `TopicBackgroundTask` is two different **class**

This doesn't work for me. Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to inflate the layout again in `onPostExecute()`

You need to re-use layout which was given in `onCreateView()`,
so you will have to create a global variable view,
set it in `onCreateView()` instead of directly returning it.

like -
`myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);`

and in `onPostExecute()`,

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)mContainer.findViewById(R.id.mylinearLayout);

    TextView text = new TextView(linearLayout.getContext());
                text.setText("TEST");
                text.setTextSize(30);

                Log.d("View", "Start");
                try {
                    linearLayout.addView(text);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: `Home` fragment and `TopicBackgroundTask` is two different **class** + you can't call `View` from `onCreateView()` i try to add `getActivity().setContentView(mContainer);` and it work but it show outside the Fragment

Answer (score 0):

I **found** the solution you must cast the `View` of the `Layout` **To** `ViewGroup`

```
protected void onPostExecute(String json) {

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
        JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
        String code = JO.getString("code");
        String message = JO.getString("message");

        if (code.equals("true")) {
            /**********************************/

            LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
            View mContainer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null);
           // LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)mContainer.findViewById(R.id.mylinearLayout);

            TextView text = new TextView(linearLayout.getContext());
            text.setText("TEST");
            text.setTextSize(30);

            Log.d("View", "Start");
            try {
                ((ViewGroup)activity.findViewById(R.id.mylinearLayout)).addView(text);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```